# How to push element to the last place in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So i have the data of patients in the database(mongodb) and in the frontend to see the whole list of patients i map through all the patients. I've added the the boolean type to patient if the patient is archived or not. If the patient is archived it is not possible to click on it and to see the data informations. How to make that if the patient is archived it will be displayed at the bottom of the list ? Should I use push function?  [image: some screens:][image]

Here is the code:

```
const PatientListScreen = ({ history, match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const patientList = useSelector((state) => state.patientList);
  const { loading, error, patients } = patientList;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  const patientDelete = useSelector((state) => state.patientDelete);
  const {
    loading: loadingDelete,
    error: errorDelete,
    success: successDelete,
  } = patientDelete;

  const patientCreate = useSelector((state) => state.patientCreate);
  const {
    loading: loadingCreate,
    error: errorCreate,
    success: successCreate,
    patient: createdPatient,
  } = patientCreate;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: PATIENT_CREATE_RESET });

    if (!userInfo.isAdmin) {
      history.push("/login");
    }
    if (successCreate) {
      history.push(`/admin/patient/${createdPatient._id}/edit`);
    } else {
      dispatch(listPatients());
    }
  }, [
    dispatch,
    history,
    userInfo,
    successDelete,
    successCreate,
    createdPatient,
  ]);

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure")) {
      dispatch(deletePatient(id));
    }
  };
  const createPatientHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createPatient());
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Row className="align-items-center">
        <Col>
          <h1>Patients List</h1>
        </Col>
        <Col className="text-right">
          <Button className="my-3" onClick={createPatientHandler}>
            <i className="fas fa-plus"></i> Create Patient
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      {loadingDelete && <Loader />}
      {errorDelete && <Message variant="danger">{errorDelete}</Message>}
      {loadingCreate && <Loader />}
      {errorCreate && <Message variant="danger">{errorCreate}</Message>}
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <ListGroup>
          <ListGroupItem className="border-dark">
            {patients.map((patient) => (
              <Row key={patient._id} className="align-items-center">
                <Col>
                  <Card className="my-3 p-3 border-dark rounded patient-item">
                    <Link to={`/admin/patientlist/${patient._id}`}>
                      <Row>
                        <Col
                          md="auto"
                          as="h5"
                          className="text-center patient-item-Col"
                        >
                          Name: {patient.name}
                        </Col>
                        <Col as="h5" className="text-center patient-item-Col">
                          Age: {patient.age}
                        </Col>
                        <Col as="h5" className="text-center patient-item-Col">
                          Sex: {patient.sex}
                        </Col>
                        <Col
                          md="auto"
                          as="h5"
                          className="text-center patient-item-Col"
                        >
                          Birth: {patient.birth}
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Link>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md="auto" className="text-right">
                  <LinkContainer to={`/admin/patient/${patient._id}/edit`}>
                    <Button id="button" variant="secondary" className="btn-sm">
                      <i className="fas fa-edit"></i>
                    </Button>
                  </LinkContainer>
                  <Button
                    variant="danger"
                    className="btn-sm"
                    onClick={() => deleteHandler(patient._id)}
                  >
                    <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                  </Button>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            ))}
          </ListGroupItem>
        </ListGroup>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PatientListScreen;
```

Comment: push, by definition, adds an element to the last place in an array - please add relevant code to the question, once you change your code, that link will change, making the question irrelevant to future readers

Comment: Might you please add a [mcve] to your question?  From [ask]: *If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also **copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've added the code of the list of patients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. i've found the solution.I've just added to the patients API sort function. It looks like that

````
  const patients = await Patient.find({});
  patients.sort();
  res.json(patients);
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

this example use the `reverse()` function for sort element element from the bottom(last) to Top(first)

```
NameArray.reverse().map((text, index) => (
<span key={index}>
    {text.name}
    
</span>
 ));
```

Comment: I don't think this is what op asked for. Sounds more like a ui element sorting problem.

Comment: Thanks @BDL , I'll delete the answer

Comment: the push will add the new element to the array. I just want to sort element that the patients that are archived will be at the bottom of the list

Comment: @KamilWojtczyk i update my answer try this solution with the reverse fu,ction